# FOSUserBundle/Symfony2: Validation Constraints not being checked against at all for the User entity

Tags: symfony, fosuserbundle

I have validation constraints defined in my validation.yml for my User
entity, but none of them are actually being called; it was working at
one point but now none of the three constraints are being checked for.
I get SQL unique constraint errors, so it's definitely not being
handled in the code properly.

Here's my validation.yml:

```
Acme\CPBundle\Entity\User:
   constraints:
        - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: { fields: username, message: userExists }
        - FOS\UserBundle\Validator\Unique: {property: usernameCanonical, message: userExists}
        - Callback:
            methods: [isTimeZoneValid]
   properties:
        firstName:
            - MaxLength: 255
        lastName:
            - MaxLength: 255
        username:
            - NotBlank: { groups: [create_user] }
            - MinLength: { limit: 4, groups: [create_user] }
            - MaxLength: { limit: 50, groups: [create_user] }
        email:
            - NotBlank: { groups: [create_user, edit_user] }
            - MaxLength: { limit: 255, groups: [create_user, edit_user] }
            - Email:
                message: The email "{{ value }}" is not a valid email
                checkMX: true
        plainPassword:
            - NotBlank:  { groups: [create_user] }
            - MinLength: { limit: 6, groups: [create_user], message: "passwordMin {{ limit }}" }
        newPassword:
            - MinLength: { limit: 6, groups: [edit_user], message: "passwordMin {{ limit }}" }
        singleRole:
            - Choice: { callback: getAllowedRoles }
```

and here's my User Entity:

```
<?php

namespace Acme\CPBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use FOS\UserBundle\Model\User as BaseUser;
use Acme\CPBundle\Constant\SecurityConstant;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\ExecutionContext;

/**
* Acme\CPBundle\Entity\User
*/
class User extends BaseUser {

/**
* @var \Acme\CPBundle\Entity\Organization $organization
*/
private $organization;

/**
* @var string $firstName
*/
private $firstName;

/**
* @var string $lastName
*/
private $lastName;

/**
* @var DateTime $timeZone
*/
private $timeZone;

/**
* @var Role $singleRole
*/
private $singleRole;

/**
* @var ArrayCollection $sessions
*/
private $sessions;


/**
* @var integer $id
*/
protected $id;

public function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
    $this->enabled = true;
    $this->sessions = new ArrayCollection();
}

public function setFirstName($firstName) {
    $this->firstName = $firstName;
}

public function getFirstName() {
    return $this->firstName;
}

public function setLastName($lastName) {
    $this->lastName = $lastName;
}

public function getLastName() {
    return $this->lastName;
}

public function setTimeZone($timeZone) {
    $this->timeZone = $timeZone;
}

public function getTimeZone() {
    return $this->timeZone;
}

public function getId() {
    return $this->id;
}

public function setOrganization(\Acme\CPBundle\Entity\Organization
    $organization) {
        $this->organization = $organization;
}

public function getOrganization() {
    return $this->organization;
}

public function setSingleRole($singleRole) {
    $this->singleRole = $singleRole;
}

public function getSingleRole() {
    return $this->singleRole;
}

public function setSessions($sessions) {
    $this->sessions = $sessions;
}

public function getSessions() {
    return $this->sessions;
}

/*
* Form Validation Methods
*/
public static function getAllowedRoles() {
    return array(SecurityConstant::ROLE_ADMIN,
        SecurityConstant::ROLE_ORG_ADMIN, SecurityConstant::ROLE_USER);
}

public function isTimeZoneValid(ExecutionContext $context) {
    $timeZoneIdentifiers = \DateTimeZone::listIdentifiers();
    if (!in_array($this->getTimeZone(), $timeZoneIdentifiers)) {
        $propertyPath = $context->getPropertyPath() . '.timeZone';
        $context->setPropertyPath($propertyPath);
        $context->addViolation('timeZoneInvalid', array(), null);
    }
}
```

I've been trying to figure this out for days, but I have no slightest
idea of what the problem may be.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Apparently, you can also set the groups like any other constraints.

```
constraints:
    - Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Validator\Constraints\UniqueEntity: { fields: username, groups: [create_user, default], message: userExists }
    - FOS\UserBundle\Validator\Unique: { property: usernameCanonical, groups: [create_user, default], message: userExists }
    - Callback:
        methods: [isTimeZoneValid]
        groups: [create_user, default]
```

Comment: Thank you! It took me an hour of searching and trying before I found this.

Comment: Having the same issue. Did you add this to validation.yml